# Django/ReportLab: pdf print do not works on alwaysdata

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab

I just have deployed an update of my project on alwaysdata.net
All works except pdf print

I do not have any error and looking browser debug network request status is 200

but I can not find my pdf anywhere

in local, pdf is save in download folder

Comment: I have a look in log files in log admin/logs/uwsgi folder

Comment: io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Comment: SystemError: <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile> returned a result with an error set

Answer (score 0):

fix by settings alwysdata site wsgi :
Site/Edit/Advanced settings : 
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true